# how to populate the second drop down using the selected value in first drop down?

Tags: php, jquery

Say I have two drop downs which are populated when the my jsp loads

```
 <select id="Group" name="group"> -- first drop down
    <option value="0001">1</option>
    <option value="0002">2</option>
 </select>

 <select id="subGroup" name="class"> -- second drop down
    <option value="0001-000">A</option> -- sub group associated with option value 001
    <option value="0001-010">B</option>
    <option value="0001-020">C</option>
    <option value="0001-030">D</option>
    <option value="0001-040">E/option>
    <option value="0002-000">F</option> -- sub group associated with option value 002
    <option value="0002-010">G</option>
    <option value="0002-020">H</option>
    <option value="0002-040">I</option>
  </select>
```

Now I need to filter the second drop down based on the selected value in first drop down. I can't use the PHP code which uses the DB callback methods. in my script I have something like this.

```
   $("#Group").change(function() {
     var groupVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
     $('#subGroup option').filter(function( {return!$(this).val().indexOf(groupVal)!=-1);}).remove();
    });
```

the script is working fine, it removes all the options other then the one selected. but my problem is that next time when i select other value in first drop down, second drop down goes empty. I even worked with hide/show but guess they wont work with `<select>` :(

is there any way by which I can repopulate the second drop down when I selected some other option in first drop down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are removing elements, you aren't getting them back. Use `hide()` and `show()` as you yourself suggested:

```
$("#Group").change(function() {
    var groupVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $('#subGroup option').hide();
    $('#subGroup option[value^='+groupVal+']').show();
});
```

In other words, every time the `#Group` selectbox is changed, hide all options in `#subGroup` and show only the ones whose `value` attribute starts with `groupVal`.

Comment: thanks a ton.. it worked.. :) but i can see the older value in the box whenever i select some another option in first drop down. once i click on the second drop down it goes away.. how this can be solved..??

Comment: I guess you're using IE? You can try binding also `click` in addition to `change`, but I'll give you no guarantees.

Comment: i tried binding both ways but its not working in IE.. its working in mozilla... :(

Comment: Thats because IE doesnt allow CSS hiding of elements via display: none; Yo uhave to compeltely remove them and then put them back on the fly. Thats whay i gave the response i did.

Answer (score 0):

Store all the options for the second select box into a array when the page loads. Then populate the select box from that array on change.
You are removing the second "batch" of options so they don't exists any more the next time you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to store all available options somewhere and then repopulate from that data set. for example

```
 var availableOptions = {
    'groupOne': {/* options as {value: '', text: ''} */},
    'groupTwo': {/* options as {value: '', text: ''} */}
  };

  $("#Group").change(function() { 
    var groupVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); 
    var sub = $('#Subgroup');
    $.each(availableOptions[groupVal], function(i, data){
      sub.append('<option value="'+data+'">'+data.text+'</option>');
  });
```

Comment: actually these drop downs are populated from database using fuego tags.. an the drop down list is too big (~15k) so cant store each subgroup as a variable..

Comment: But youve already incurred the wight of those options becuase youve got them written into html - which is going to be even more weighty than a compressed js/json notation object. Anyhow you cant hide options in ie so if you need xbrowser support youre stuck with removing appending them. So you can either store them in a simle object/array, a hidden select/div element, or you can buld them with ajax call on change of that first select.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a related select box plugin by Remy sharp that I've had success with if you want to try:

http://remysharp.com/2007/09/18/auto-populate-multiple-select-boxes/