# Using JQuery to refresh a second drop down List relating to the first drop down list

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 drop down lists on my homepage:

- To firstly let the user select the 'County'
- To secondly let the user select the 'Town'- related to that County'

The town is related to the County by relating the County's Name and the Town's Name.

What I want to be able to do is:

Once the visitor selects the 'County' some way, the second Drop Down refreshes only to reveal the towns that are related to the County within the database.

I would appreciate any help and coding examples for the SQL Queries and Refreshes etc..

Many thanks,

Comment: duplicate of [how to populate the second drop down using the selected value in first drop down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862148/how-to-populate-the-second-drop-down-using-the-selected-value-in-first-drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

Assuming that you have a CGI responsible for retrieve the data, you have the following workflow:

1. The only visible dropdown list is the first one.
2. When the user chooses the "county" you send a request to the CGI with the first value to
   retrieve all the possible "Tows".
3. Then you populate your second dropdown list with the CGI answer and show it to the user.

CGI

It is not possible to show you the right query because I don't know your database. By the way, do you have any database? That is certainly the hard part (at least in my country it is hard to find one).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Yes I do have a database which they are stored in. The actual County's and Town's are added within the Administration panel. by CGI, would you mean I need to implement a CGI script? I am working in PHP and Javascript, can this still be possible?