# Dynamic drop down updates based on another drop down

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm hoping someone can help steer me in the right direction.  I currently have a file, which I will call data.php.  In this file I have the following data:

```
$sports_arr = array();
$sports_arr[] = "Basketball";
$sports_arr[] = "Baseball";
$sports_arr[] = "Football";
```

I also have the following arrays in the same data.php file:

```
$position = array();
$position['Basketball'][] = "Power Forward";
$position['Basketball'][] = "Small Forward";
$position['Basketball'][] = "Center";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Center Forward";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Right Wing";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Left Wing";
$position['Football'][] = "Halfback";
$position['Football'][] = "Fullback";
$position['Football'][] = "Wide Reciever";
$position['Football'][] = "Tight End";
$position['Football'][] = "Center";
```

The issue is I am trying to figure out how to have the first dropdown, which is currently populating with the following code:

```
<div class="selectStyled">
    <select name="Sport1" class="styled">
    <option id="default" value="">Your Sport</option>
        <?php natsort($sports_arr);
        foreach ($sports_arr as $key => $val) { 
            echo "<option value='" . $val . "' id='position" . $key . "'>" . $val . "</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is where I am running in to problems.  What I am wanting is based on the result of the dropdown above (e.g. the user chooses baseball), I want a second subsequent drop down to populate with the correct position array.  So if they choose basketball, it would populate the second drop down on the page instantly and dynamically with the basketball positions.  If they change their mind and choose Football, it would dynamically populate the second drop down with the football positions.

Any help here is appreciated.  I'm hitting a major road block...  Thank you!!

Comment: you do it using ajax.

Comment: http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Call an ajax function and pass the related key and load the drop down.

Comment: use normal javascript/jquery !!

Comment: plz read this one i hope this one help something<br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862148/how-to-populate-the-second-drop-down-using-the-selected-value-in-first-drop-down?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
<?php
$sports_arr = array();
$sports_arr[] = "Basketball";
$sports_arr[] = "Baseball";
$sports_arr[] = "Football";

$position = array();
$position['Basketball'][] = "Power Forward";
$position['Basketball'][] = "Small Forward";
$position['Basketball'][] = "Center";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Center Forward";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Right Wing";
$position['Soccer'][] = "Left Wing";
$position['Football'][] = "Halfback";
$position['Football'][] = "Fullback";
$position['Football'][] = "Wide Reciever";
$position['Football'][] = "Tight End";
$position['Football'][] = "Center";
?>

<div class="home">
    <select id="s1">
        <?php foreach($sports_arr as $sa) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sa; ?>"><?php echo $sa; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select id="s2">
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s1= document.getElementById("s1");
var s2 = document.getElementById("s2");
onchange(); //Change options after page load
s1.onchange = onchange; // change options when s1 is changed

function onchange() {
    <?php foreach ($sports_arr as $sa) {?>
        if (s1.value == '<?php echo $sa; ?>') {
            option_html = "";
            <?php if (isset($position[$sa])) { ?> // Make sure position is exist
                <?php foreach ($position[$sa] as $value) { ?>
                    option_html += "<option><?php echo $value; ?></option>";
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            s2.innerHTML = option_html;
        }
    <?php } ?>
}
</script>
```

Most time, people use ajax, but if your network is slow, ajax is not good way.

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thank you so much for the help!  Going to work on incorporating this in to my current code base...  The += part of the code is something that I learned from... any idea where I can find out more about this to learn more?  I must be using the wrong search terms in google.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

you want to if user select basketball from the first drop-down, all the records of basketball array display in second drop-down.

so you should use AJAX function on onChange() event of first drop-down.